# How to call remote JVM class method

Tags: java

My application code will run on one box. I have a tool that will be executed on a different box. Here I want to access my application code specific class method in the tool where it will executed on different box. How can I do this?

I don't want to change any existing code on the application side, I only want to add code on tool side to access the application class method. The class that I want to access is a regular java bean class.

Answer (score 1):

We used to have a somehow similar issue.

We end up creating a simple library that allow us to distribute classes over several JVMs and to call methods in remote JVM.

You can have a look on https://github.com/plantuml/remotejvm to see if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to have a look at [Remote Method Invocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation). Also take care of which version you are using, versions before Java 5.0 required the RMI stubs to be compiled separately.

- [Java RMI Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html)
- [RMI online training](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to take a look at remote method invocation(RMI). It is not possible without adding code on the application side since you need to register the application with the RMI registry. The RMI registry is sort of a directory lookup to allow remote applications to access the application.

You could also use RMI-IIOP but it has the same constraints. You need to register the application with tnameserv

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/index.html

Comment: JNDI is only an API. You seem to be talking about the RMI Registry.